# Removing upper and lower CI from annotations in Metafor

Tags: r, plot, metafor

I'm using the Metafor package to plot forest plots and I was wondering if anyone knew a way to omit the upper and lower CIs from the text annotations, for example where one group is a reference and outcome is fixed at 1.

Here is an example:

```
library(metafor)

par(mar=c(5,4,1,2))

forest(x     = c(1, 0.9, 1.1),
       ci.ub = c(1, 0.98, 1.18),
       ci.lb = c(1, 0.82, 1.02),
       refline = 1)
```

[image]

I would like to remove [1.00, 1.00] from the Study 1 row only, leaving just 1.00.

The only possibility I can think of would be to plot something in white over the top of these, but this would be fiddly, and I have a large complex plot with many groups.

Comment: Selectively omitting the CI information is not possible. I can see how this might be useful based on your use case, but I am hesitant to add yet another argument to the `forest` function (which already has way too many). And you would have to supply a logical vector that indicates whether to show the CI for a particular row or not. If you have that info, just plotting white boxes (with `rect`) at these rows is pretty much the same thing. I've done something like this myself.

Comment: I take your point. Anyway thanks for a great package, it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You could play around with the graph produced by the call to the `forest` function, removing the annotation on the right-hand side with the option `annotate = FALSE`. After that, you could opt to add your own text with the function `text` (with limited possibilities) like in the code below.

```
library(metafor)
par(mar=c(5,4,1,2))

forest(x     = c(1, 0.9, 1.1),
       ci.ub = c(1, 0.98, 1.18),
       ci.lb = c(1, 0.82, 1.02),
       refline = 1,
       annotate = FALSE,   ### added
       )

text(x = c(1.25, 1.25, 1.25), y = c(3, 2, 1), 
     label=c("1.00", "0.90", "1.10"))
```

This yields the following graph:

[image]

Comment: You're right that this is a possibility, but it's not very practical in my case. Firstly I only want to remove it from specific rows (where there is a reference group) and secondly I have a large complex forest plot and I would have to manually type out the annotations to be re-added or write new code to concatenate the upper and lower CI intervals. Basically, it would still be easier just to remove the text after plotting with an image editor, which is what I've been doing.

Comment: @Joe I understand. When looking at the documentation, the function you are using has simply not been built with that kind of manipulation in mind.